# References are missing after migrating Unreal assets

Tags: unreal-4, export

I'm currently trying to migrate some VFX assets (meshes, materials, textures, material instances, niagara emitters and niagara systems) to another project on another machine.

My folder structure looks like this: C:\Users\Documents\MyName\UnrealProjects\MyProject\Content\ThirdPersonBP\MyVFX

My current workflow is like this:

1. In Unreal I right click on "MyVFX" and choose to migrate it and then choose a destination folder (not another project).
2. Zip the migrated folder and put it on another machine.
3. Unzip "MyVFX" from the zip to C:\Users\Documents\OtherName\UnrealProjects\OtherProject\Content\ThirdPersonBP
4. Put the niagara system into the level

The problem that now occurs is that references are not set. For example, the Sample Texture node in a material does not contain a set texture or a niagara system does not have anything set in the Mesh Renderer module (neither mesh nor material).

Everything works again as intended once the references are set again manually. But, that's tedious work of course and I don't want my teammates to do that for every effect I create.

Comment: Try to fixup redirectors before the mograte

Comment: @ColdSteel that didn't make a difference :(

Comment: You may want to check the Unreal bug tracker and see if anyone has encountered this - you've a better chance of getting a reply from an Unreal Dev on the Unreal Forusm

Comment: Try to unzip to content and not to content/thirdpersonBP since migration assumes it is going to be in content and nowhere else

Comment: @ColdSteel this didn't make any difference, unfortunately.